# Set focus between updatepanels

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have two updatepanels. If the first textbox get's triggered I update the DropDownList in the second updatepanel. This works in codebehind with:

```
Protected Sub tb1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tb1.TextChanged
    'code for the databind
    ddl2.DataBind()
    up2.Update()
End Sub
```

Now how do I set the focus on the dropdownlist in the second updatepanel?

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager
    ID="tsm1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:textbox id="tb1" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tb1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up2" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl2" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I work in .NET 4.5 and ajaxControlToolkit 7.1213.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed to using javascript or jQuery, you can put some in the second update panel after the dropdownlist to check the textbox value and if it's not empty, set focus on the dropdownlist.  That way each time the second update panel is reloaded, the script will execute.  Here's an example of what I'm talking about, this code has not been tested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var txtbox = document.getElementById('up1');

if(txtbox != undefined && txtbox.value != '')
{
    document.getElementById("up2").focus();
}
</script>
```

EDIT - After some research I found that this solution may work better, give it a shot:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);    

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
    document.getElementById("ddl2").focus();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising, but I can't get it to work. I presume I need to use tb1 and ddl2 instead of up1 and up2? but it doesn't trigger after the update of updatepanel2